# Star x-axes with 1 with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a list with numbers like this:

```
pdf = PdfPages('test.pdf')
pyplot.plot([1,2,4,7,8], color='#3399FF')
pyplot.ylabel('Level')
pyplot.xlabel('Number of actions')
pyplot.suptitle('Battery')
pdf.savefig()
pyplot.close()
```

The problem is that the x-axes start with 0 and that makes things a bit confusing in my solution. Because then it will show battery level for action 0.

Is there any way to make the x-axes start from 1?

Comment: use pyplot.`xlim(xmin=1)`

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the problem with that one is that I will lose my first number. So the x-axes will start with 1 but the first number will be 2.

I would like a solution that let me start with 1 in the x-axes, but start with my first number in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dat = [1,2,4,7,8]
pyplot.plot(np.arange(len(dat)) + 1, dat, color='#3399FF')
pyplot.ylabel('Level')
pyplot.xlabel('Number of actions')
pyplot.suptitle('Battery')
pyplot.xlim(xmin=1)
```

Comment: Sorry but this seems to give me "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension"